# KeyError: 'user_available'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement a check that if a user is available then render a specific template. I am using this condition  `if session['user_available']:` where session is imported from flask. But I am getting `KeyError: 'user_available'` error. If this method is deprecated then what is the updated code for assessing the availability of current user using session.

Comment: The method is not deprecated. At the time of the request, the value with this key is not yet set in the session. Hence the error message.

Comment: How can I set it.

Comment: I don't know your code so I can't tell you. But you can ask if the key has already been set. `if 'user_available' in session` That, along with the actual query, should deliver the result without throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of the request, the key-value pair does not exist in the session. This results in the KeyError.
Much of this session is to be used like a dict. So you can query if a key-value pair exists within the session. This should assume that even if the key is not part of the session, no KeyError is thrown.

```
if 'user_available' in session and session['user_available']:
    # The key is present in the session and the value is set.
```

Comment: I was not setting the value.Thanks